# Генератор рандомных слов на русском

Tags: python, строки, случайные-числа, словари

Нужен генератор слов на python, знаю что для этого есть пакет Random-Words. Есть ли альтернативы для других языков? Итальянский, испанский, португальский в приоритете.

Знаю такой способ

```
import requests

Word_site = "http://svnweb.freebsd.org/csrg/share/dict/words?view=co&content-type=text/plain"

response = requests.get(Word_site)
WORDS = response.content.splitlines()
```

Но опять же, здесь импорт именно английского словаря

Comment: А нельзя просто иметь словарь и выбрать случайное слово?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я предлагаю хранить слова локально, в txt файле (в таком виде их проще всего добыть)
Соответственно код:

```
with open('dict.txt', 'r') as file:
    words = file.readlines().
    words = [s.strip("\n") for s in words]
```

Пишем генератор случайного слова

```
import random
def random_word(words):
   return random.choice (words)
```

Список слов можно спокойно скачать из интернета. Например
https://github.com/dwyl/english-words/blob/master/words.txt
http://blog.harrix.org/article/3334

Переводите этот запрос на нужный вам язык при помощи Google Translator и в выдаче один из первых сайтов будет содержать нужную вам информацию
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Так же если вы не можете найти список слов в открытом доступе, или не можете его использовать по корпоративным соображениям, список слов можно легко спарсерить например с википедии, или другого веб-сайта. На нужном языке открывается 1000-3000 страниц и все слова, которых еще нет в словарике добавляются. Вся эта процедура займёт пару часов, но у вас будет хоть неполный, но достаточный для рандомной генерации слов словарик.